# views created in django-page-CMS disables all CSS? code included, a fix please

Tags: css, django, django-templates, django-views, django-cms

I am using Django-page-CMS

Everything works fine However once I create my own views which extend from pages used within the CMS the CSS does not display.

This is strange because these pages display the CSS fine, as long as I do not use my own views.

I would greatly appreciate some help on this matter or at least some suggestions on why this is happening and how it could be rectified.

I am using the static files trick.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^admin_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

Here is how I have linked styles....links to jquery also exist but this should not affect.

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/style.css" />
</head>
```

I have some styles in pages which extend the base linked in the following way....

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block page_style %}
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/index.css" />
{% endblock %}
```

Again, Everything works fine until I create my own views and pages which extend from any of these pages. Once I view the new pages no css displays in any page. not even the base however if I do not use my own views everything is displayed fine. I would greatly appreciate help on this matter.

Comment: Do you mean it works flawlessly with cms generated pages? Is the HTML of the rendered pages ok, especially the links to the css files?

Comment: Yes it works flawlessly with the cms generated pages. Absolutely fine. Then as soon as I create a view with a template that extends one of those beautifully styled pages. All the styles disappear. Strange, its basically telling me if I want to use my own views I cant use my styles!

Comment: I would greatly appreciate some help with this

Comment: Post the code how/where you integrate your styles!

Comment: the Code has  been posted. All files are in the correct directory.

Comment: Give us some output to your browser (raw HTML please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MEDIA_URL was not coming through properly.

RequestContext() was the problem. The content_instance was not set therefore the MEDIA_URL variable would not come through when the template was rendered.

When using render_to_response.....

```
return render_to_response(YOUR_TEMPLATE, YOUR_TEMPLATE_CONTEXT,
context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your {% block page_style %}{% endblock %} should be within  of base.html

So base.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

yourtemplate.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/index.css" />
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Nope unfortunately it makes no difference. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The base actually stops working when it is placed within {% block page_style %} this cannot be right.